# How to solve this differential equation sinusoidal?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry

I can't find how to separate variables.
$$y= \sin(xy')$$

Comment: Take the inverse sine and then separate variables.

Comment: The variables cannot be separated in this case. $\sin(xy)$ is not of the type $f(x)g(y)$ for any pair $f,g$.

Comment: dy/sin^(-1)⁡y =dx/x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set $x y'(x)=u(x)$, then the differentiation of the original equation become:

$$u=x u'\cos u \implies \frac{dx}{du}=\frac{x \cos u}{u}\implies \frac{dx}{x}=\frac{ \cos u}{u}du$$